# Using navigator.language with node-webkit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, localization, webkit

I am trying to localize my webkit app and have been looking for solutions to get the users preferred language from their OS.

My question is, how exactly does webkit handle calls like navigator.language? It does seem to work for what I need, I made a new user account and changed the windows display language to Japanese and it returned ja. I just want to make sure this would be a consistent way to detect the users OS language. Any information regarding this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the navagator.language uses the OS language, it works in almost all cases

Comment: That's good to hear. This will be consistent across different operating systems as well?

Comment: yeah, the browser cares about that to you :), it will return something like en-US, pt-BR saying the language and the country